# couldn't create react native app using yarn

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yarnpkg

So, using `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` uses yarn by default and throws me this error

```
Error: Couldn't find the "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-NllVWC\node_modules\react-native\template.config.js file inside "react-native" template. Please make sure the template is valid.
```

But passing `--npm` like this `npx react-native init AwesomeProject --npm` works just fine.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If Your Using Expo then You Can

```
yarn global add expo-cli
```

then Simply

```
expo init app-name
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to create a bare react-native project

Comment: see if this [link](https://yarnpkg.com/package/react-native-cli)  could help